# LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates, frequency and GPS icon

Tags: java, android, gps

I have a Service that is getting location updates using `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates`.

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                          minTimeMillis,
                          minDistanceMeters,
                          locationListener);
```

I've found that if I set a low frequency for updates (e.g. 30 or 60 seconds) the 'location' or 'GPS' icon in the status bar appears and remains on whilst my listener is active.

But, if I set a low frequency like 5 minutes, the icon never appears. My app continues to function and I seem to be receiving updated locations.

Is this behavior expected, or documented anywhere? Is the phone still updating the GPS location for my app, or just fetching from a cache (i.e. is there a risk of reduced accuracy)?

Comment: i think gps icon only shown when get location using gps provider not network provider

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I'm using the GPS provider.

Comment: are you sure not both provider?

Comment: Yes, just GPS. I added the code above.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve it? Thanks.